# Imprimir vários números com um separador entre eles, mas não colocar o separador após o último

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

> Faça um programa que leia dois números inteiros, representando os valores inicio e fim de um intervalo e imprima os múltiplos de 5 entre eles.

Meu código:

```
valores = input().split()    
numero1 = int(valores[0])    
numero2 = int(valores[1])    
for n in range(numero1, numero2+1):

    if n % 5 == 0:

        print(n, end='|')
```

Notem que os números são separados por `|`, mas não pode ter esse caractere depois do último número.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é do segundo em diante imprimir um| antes do número.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print('|'.join(str(n) for n in range(numero1, numero2 + 1) if n % 5 == 0))
```

Apesar de parecer a mesma coisa da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462372/112052), tem uma diferença. Lá foi criada uma lista contendo os números, depois esta lista foi passada para `join`. Aqui eu passei diretamente a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), que não cria a lista. Assim, o `join` itera pelos números e já vai construindo a string final (não que vá ter *aquela* diferença de performance - ainda mais para *ranges* com poucos valores - mas é importante saber que você pode construir o que precisa sem criar listas - ou quaisquer outras estruturas - sem necessidade).

---

Mas na verdade existe outra forma de otimizar o código. Se a ideia é imprimir apenas os múltiplos de 5, não tem porque o `range` ser de 1 em 1 e ir testando se cada número é divisível por 5 (já que entre 2 múltiplos, outros 4 números serão testados sem necessidade). Em vez disso, você pode simplesmente começar em um múltiplo de 5 e fazer o `range` ir de 5 em 5:

```
numero1 = # ler o número
numero2 = # ler o número

# se não for múltiplo de 5, ajustar para o próximo múltiplo
resto = numero1 % 5
if resto != 0:
    numero1 += 5 - resto

# range pula de 5 em 5
print('|'.join(map(str, range(numero1, numero2 + 1, 5))))
```

Dessa forma, eu só preciso testar se o primeiro número é divisível por 5. Se for, não precisa fazer nada. Se não for, eu ajusto para o próximo múltiplo (por exemplo, se for 7, ajusto para 10). Como agora eu sei que estou começando com um múltiplo de 5, o `range` pode iterar de 5 em 5, e assim eu não preciso testar dentro do *loop* se os números são divisíveis por 5 (na verdade nem precisa mais do `for`: eu posso passar o `range` diretamente, pois agora ele só terá múltiplos de 5).

Uma alternativa ao `join` é imprimir o `range` diretamente:

```
numero1 = # ler o número
numero2 = # ler o número

# se não for múltiplo de 5, ajustar para o próximo múltiplo
resto = numero1 % 5
if resto != 0:
    numero1 += 5 - resto

print(*range(numero1, numero2 + 1, 5), sep='|')
```

Note o asterisco antes do `range`: ele serve para fazer o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) dos valores do `range` (é como se eu passasse cada um deles separadamente para `print`), e o parâmetro `sep` indica o caractere que será impresso entre os elementos (é mais ou menos o que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462355/112052) sugeriu, mas sem precisar criar a lista).

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), que itera pelos números e seus respectivos índices. Assim, você não imprime o caractere `|` somente para o primeiro elemento:

```
numero1 = # ler o número
numero2 = # ler o número

# se não for múltiplo de 5, ajustar para o próximo múltiplo
resto = numero1 % 5
if resto != 0:
    numero1 += 5 - resto

for i, n in enumerate(range(numero1, numero2 + 1, 5)):
    if i > 0: # não é o primeiro número, coloca o separador
        print('|', end='')
    print(n, end='')
```

Ou não use o índice, simplesmente verifique se o número é igual ao primeiro:

```
numero1 = # ler o número
numero2 = # ler o número

# se não for múltiplo de 5, ajustar para o próximo múltiplo
resto = numero1 % 5
if resto != 0:
    numero1 += 5 - resto

for n in range(numero1, numero2 + 1, 5):
    if n != numero1: # não é o primeiro número, coloca o separador
        print('|', end='')
    print(n, end='')
```

Comment: Seus 2 últimos exemplos (enumerate e sem índice) estão printando números não múltiplos de cinco: 1, 6, 11, 16...

Comment: @Evilmaax Deixei o código completo em todos os exemplos para evitar mais confusões :-)

Comment: Boooa, valeu @hkotsubo

Comment: Muito obrigado, não conhecia esse join e nem esse map, agora entendo seus usos e obrigado também por demonstrar várias formas de fazer .

Answer (score 4):

**Sem considerar que você não está tratando o input**, uma maneira fácil de juntar os números seria colocando todos eles em uma lista de strings e usar o método `join()` para imprimir o resultado.

Esse método é esperto o suficiente para fazer exatamente o que você quer, ou seja, só colocar o separador entre os elementos.

O código do laço `for` e da condição `if` fica todo em uma compreensão de lista. Cada elemento é convertido para o tipo `str`, para que o `join()` funcione.

Ficaria assim:

```
valores = input().split()    
numero1 = int(valores[0])    
numero2 = int(valores[1])

lista = [str(n) for n in range(numero1, numero2+1) if n % 5 == 0]

print('|'.join(lista))
```